# AG-Grid - How to increase row height dynamically?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

This question is related to Ag-Grid row height on Angular 4 Project. Please see the below scenario:-

I have an Ag-Gird having 3 columns respectively:-

1. **Id** (resizable column from UI)
2. **Name** (resizable column from UI)
3. **Address** (resizable column from UI)

I do **not** have any limitations( like the limited number of character or words is allowed) on **Address** column. Users can type any number of characters or words they want to.

**Issues:-**

1. How to increase the row height, when Address column width is completely filled-up with words or when users press **Enter** or **Shift + Enter**?
2. How to adjust height automatically when users resize the Address column?

Please help me with these issues.

Thanks

Comment: Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that people can help you easily. See how to create [mcve]

Comment: @Paritosh ,Please find the issue on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/aggrid. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple things to be taken care.

Have a look at the updated [<kbd>Stackblitz</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/aggrid-bubtty?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

1. Have `cellClass: "cell-wrap-text"` attribute in the `ColDef` for `Address` column and have the appropriate CSS
2. Handle `columnResized` event so that `this.gridApi.resetRowHeights()` can be called to adjust the height of the rows whenever the column is resized
3. Also handle `cellEditingStopped` event, so that when the data for the column is updated, the row height also gets updated accordingly.

   ```
   onColumnResized() {
      this.gridApi.resetRowHeights();
   }
   onCellEditingStopped() {
     this.onColumnResized();
   }
   ```
4. Provide `autoHeight: true` property in the `defaultColDef`

   `defaultColDef = { autoHeight: true };`

---

### Update:

provide `cellEditor: 'agLargeTextCellEditor'` if you want to have `textarea` like control for this field.

Check this [<kbd>StackBlitz</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/aggrid-gd3pre?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried these options but it does not solve my issue i.e. I actually wanted to achieve the auto height when the user is editing Address column in-grid itself.

Comment: you can use custom cell editor for that, use `textarea` instead of `input`

Comment: The text is getting lost, when address column is resized (as the width of Id column). To reproduce this issue, please use below mentioned `rowData`.                                      
 `rowData = [
    {id: 1, name: 'XYZ', address: ``1. Building number.wing number, landmark

2. Building number.wing number, landmark

3. Building number.wing number, landmark

4. Building number.wing number, landmark

5.Building number.wing number, l``}
  ];`

Comment: not sure what are you suggesting, have a look at the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in react I wanted to increase the height of row according to the content of the text area and on enter it should go to next line in text area instead of not turning into read only, so what I did i used the suppressKeyboardEvent of ag-grid and wrote the code into it, here is my code

```
           cellClass: "description-cell",
            width: 200,
            cellRendererFramework: (params) =>{
                return <pre> {params.data.description}</pre>
            },
            cellEditor: 'agLargeTextCellEditor',
            cellEditorParams: (params) => {
                return {
                    maxLength: '1000',
                    cols: this.props.cols,
                    rows: 2
                }
            },
            suppressKeyboardEvent: (params) => {
              const KEY_ENTER = 13;
              const keyCode = params.event.keyCode;
              const gridShouldDoNothing = params.event.target.value && params.editing && keyCode === KEY_ENTER;
              params.event.target.style.height = 'inherit';
              params.event.target.style.height = `${params.event.target.scrollHeight}px`;
              params.node.setRowHeight(params.event.target.scrollHeight); // adjust it according to your requirement
              this.gridApi && this.gridApi.onRowHeightChanged();
              return gridShouldDoNothing;
          }
```

I hope this could help you or someone who is looking for it :)

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was to call `redrawRows()`

Typescript + React example:

```
const onCellEditingStopped = (event: CellEditingStoppedEvent<any>) => {
   event.api.redrawRows();
};
```