# How can I make the grid cells show the whole input text in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid

I hope you're having a good day.
So I am using ag-grid in my project to transform a bunch of excel tools(files) in one unified web-application.
So far so good.
However, I couldn't find a way to make the grid cells show the whole input text with the ag-grid framework.

In Excel:

[image: Excel cell rendering]

In ag-grid:

[image: ag-grid default cell rendering]

I hope I have made my point clear.
I have searched in the ag-grid documentation but with no result. This also seems to be the default input text cell rendering in all of their projects examples.
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/
Any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is similar to one I already answered: [AG-Grid - How to increase row height dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55277171/1417185)

Provide a CSS class for the column

```
{
  header: 'Address',
  field: 'address',
  cellClass: "cell-wrap-text",
}
```

CSS class - keep it in your root level `styles`.

```
.cell-wrap-text {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly again! You're a godsend ! Would you mind explaining what does the CSS code do exactly?

Comment: Do you mind explaining what the "!important" stands for?